# Dual citizenship different information

Tags: visas, dual-nationality, customs-and-immigration

I have two passports ( Yemen & Somalia) 
I entered Egypt with my Yemen passport 
I’m going to Germany for family reunion but the visa is on my Somali passport

The issue is I have different date of birth and place of birth in both passports

Can I book the ticket with my Somali passport which has the visa and at exit immigration show the Yemen passport that I entered with? And would it be a problem if they asked about the visa to know that Im allowed to enter Germany? and I showed them the Somali passport with the information difference?

The correct DOB is on the Yemen passport, but here’s the thing: I have two original birth certificates each proving the Date and place of birth on the related passport.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I have two passports/nationalities. How do I use them when I travel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel)

Comment: @GregHewgill Not quite a duplicate, because having conflicting basic data is an extra twist that may cause concerns about impersonation etc.

Comment: @Abdullah Ali Which date of birth is correct? Do you have any documentation to prove it?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments. Putting on hold.